# Set variable with cache force cache does not update the cmake variable

Tags: linux, cmake

I am trying to update the cmake variable based on the value of env variable if preset. And I am also caching this variable. However, it is not updating properly in cmake but in cache I can see the updated value.

Here, is my test CMakeLists.txt file

I have set evirnoment variable `compiler_verion=clang15`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(test)

if(NOT compiler_version)
    set(compiler_version "gcc")
    message("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ default ${compiler_version}")
endif()

if(NOT "$ENV{compiler_version}" STREQUAL "")
    set(compiler_version $ENV{compiler_version} CACHE STRING "which compiler to use..." FORCE)
    message("++++++++++++++++++++++++++ env compiler_version : $ENV{compiler_version} cmake_compiler_version  ${compiler_version} ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
elseif(NOT compiler_version)
    set(compiler_version "gcc" CACHE STRING "which compiler to use..." FORCE)
    message("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ else if ${compiler_version}")
else()
    set(compiler_version ${compiler_version} CACHE STRING "which compiler to use..." FORCE)
    message("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ else ${compiler_version}")
endif()
```

I am running the command

`cmake ..` from build folder.

Here is the actual output for the same.

```bash
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.5.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.5.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ default gcc
++++++++++++++++++++++++++ env compiler_verion : clang15 cmake_compiler_version  gcc ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
-- Configuring done (0.6s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /test/buil
```

My issue is with respect to this.
`++++++++++++++++++++++++++ env compiler_version : clang15 cmake_compiler_version  gcc`

Why it is not setting the `compiler_version` to `clang15`?

If I re-run this when cache file is already available, it working as expected.

```bash
++++++++++++++++++++++++++ env compiler_verion : clang15 cmake_compiler_version  clang15 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
-- Configuring done (0.0s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
```

Am I missing something?
I am using cmake version 3.26 on linux platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMake distinguishes **cache** variables, created by `set(CACHE)` command flow, and **normal** variables, created by simple `set()`. Those variables exist in separate namespaces, so it is perfectly possible to have both CACHE and normal variables with the same name. So in your case you have:

- **normal** variable `compiler_version` with the value `gcc`,
- **cache** variable `compiler_version` with the value `clang15`.

When dereference the variable using `${name}` syntax, CMake returns value of the **normal** variable if it exists. Only if the normal variable doesn't exist, CMake returns value of the cache variable. (And if neither normal nor cache variable exists, then CMake returns empty string).

So, in your case `${compiler_version}` will be evaluated as `gcc` - value of the normal variable. For read specifically a cache variable you could use `$CACHE{compiler_version}`, it will return `clang15`.

Normally, one should avoid using cache and normal variables of the same name.

---

In your case you could use only cache variable `compiler_version`:

```
set(compiler_version_default "gcc")
if(NOT "$ENV{compiler_version}" STREQUAL "")
    set(compiler_version_default $ENV{compiler_version})
endif()
set(compiler_version ${compiler_version_default} CACHE STRING "which compiler to use...")
```

That way the CMake variable could take value from the command line (via `-Dcompiler_version=...`) or from the environment variable. And the value of the CMake variable is remembered between `cmake` invocations.

---

Before CMake 3.21, which introduced the policy [CMP0126](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0126.html), the command `set(CACHE)` both set cache variable and removed the normal variable with the same name ([documentation for CMake 3.20](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.20/command/set.html#set-cache-entry)). So after

```
set(compiler_version $ENV{compiler_version} CACHE STRING "which compiler to use..." FORCE)
```

dereferencing `${compiler_version}` would return a value of the newly created variable with guarantee.

However, even with such behavior using normal and cache variables of the same name was tricky. E.g.

```
set(foo "normal_value")
set(foo "cache_value" CACHE STRING "doc ...")
message(STATUS "${foo}")
```

would print "cache_value" when run `cmake` for the first time. But when run `cmake` the second time (and following times), it will print `normal_value`, because the cache variable is already existed, so the `set(CACHE)` neither creates it nor removes the normal variable.

Comment: Thanks. 
`cmake_policy(SET CMP0126 OLD) ` solved the issue.

Comment: @SanketBhurke: Have you noted on the remark at the end of the policy documentation? "The `OLD` behavior of a policy is deprecated by definition and may be removed in a future version of CMake." Purpose of CMake policies is to solve **compatibility issues** for projects developed for older CMake versions. If you want to develop a project for work e.g. with CMake 3.15 and newer, just specify `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)`. Setting a policy to `OLD` just because "I am more comfortable with the old behavior" is discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should export the env `export compiler_version=clang15` or run cmake with `compiler_version=clang15 cmake ...`

Comment: I am already doing `export compiler_version=clang15`